# unexpected 'A' Postman php api with JSON Response

Tags: php, json, api, postman

Recently I try to create an API with PHP. all thing goes alright till suddenly I face **unexpected 'a'** error when trying to parse a JSON from the request throw Postman. I found something related to my issue but there is no solution in my case here : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40149668/postman-show-unexpected-a-in-json-response-but-json-is-well-formed)

I send

```
{

"teacher_code":"sas"
}
```

JSON to teachers.php file to assign a student to the teacher

here is the **teacher.php** file content :

```
require_once ("classes/Rest.php");
require_once ("classes/api.php");

$api = new Api();



if($api->getHttpmethod() === 'POST'){

$api->validateParameter('teacher_code' ,$teacher_code = $api->getParam('teacher_code') , STRING , true);


$api->checkUserAccessablity();

$api->teacherCodeinRange($teacher_code);



$query = "INSERT INTO `group_users` (`user_id`,`group_id` )
    VALUES (:user_id , (SELECT group_id FROM `groups` WHERE group_name = 'all' AND user_id =
    (SELECT user_id FROM `teachers` WHERE t_code = :teacher_code)) )";
$keyValue = [
    "user_id" => $api->getUserid() ,
    "teacher_code" => $teacher_code

];
$result = $api->queryExecute($query , $keyValue  );

$api->returnResponse(SUCCESS , SUCCESS_MESSAGE);




}
```

and **api.php** file :

```
require_once ("dbConnect.php");
require_once ("JWT.php");



class Api extends Rest
{
    public $dbConn;
    private $userId;
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $db = new dbConnect();
        $this->dbConn = $db->connect();

    }


    public function setUserid($id){
        $this->userId = $id;
    }
    public function getUserid(){
        return $this->userId;
    }

    public function checkUserAccessablity(){

        $payload = $this->deCodetoken();
        $this->setUserid($payload->user_id);
        $this->validateUser();


    }

    public function validateUser(){
        $query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE user_id = :id";
        $keyValue = [
            "id" => $this->getUserid()
        ];

        $result = $this->queryExecute($query , $keyValue,true );
        if(!$result){
            $this->throwError(SYSTEM_ERROR , SYSTEM_ERROR_MESSAGE );
        }
        if(!is_array($result)){
            $this->throwError(USER_NOT_FOUND_CODE , USER_NOT_FOUND_MESSAGE . $this->getUserid());
        }
        //TODO CHECK USER ACTIVE

        return true;
    }
    public function teacherCodeinRange($tCode){
        $query = "SELECT * FROM `teachers` INNER JOIN `licenses` ON (licenses.user_id =  teachers.user_id) 
                  WHERE teachers.t_code = :tcode LIMIT 1";
        $keyValue = [
            "tcode" => $tCode
        ];

         $this->queryExecute($query , $keyValue,true );


        return true;
    }


    public function teacherCodeinStudentrange($teacherID){
        //TODO SELECT TEACHER STUDENT RANGE
        $query = "SELECT DISTICT user_id FROM `teachers` INNER JOIN `groups` ON (groups.user_id = teachers.user_id)
                  INNER JOIN `group_users` ON (group_users.group_id = groups.group_id)
                  WHERE teachers.user_id = :teacherID AND groups.group_name = 'all' AND group_users.user_id = :userID  ";
        $keyValue = [
            "userID" => $this->getUserid(),
            "teacherID" => $teacherID,
        ];

        $result = $this->queryExecute($query , $keyValue,true );
        if(!is_array($result)){
            $this->throwError(TEACHER_NOT_FOUND , TEACHER_NOT_FOUND_MESSAGE);
        }

        return true;
    }


    public function getHttpmethod(){
        return $this->HttpMethod;
    }

    public function getParam($key){


        return $this->arrayFinddeep($this->data , $key);
    }
    public function queryExecute($query , $keyArray , $isSelect = false){

        $queryExec = $this->dbConn->prepare($query);


        if(is_array($keyArray) || !empty($keyArray)) {

            foreach ($keyArray as $key => &$value) {


                $queryExec->bindParam(':' . $key, $value);
            }


        }
        if($isSelect) {


            $queryExec->execute();
            $result = $queryExec->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);



        }else {
            $result = $queryExec->execute();
        }





        return $result;


    }

    public function getLastuserId(){
        return $this->dbConn->lastInsertId();
    }
    public function generateToken($payload , $secretKey){
        try{
            return \Firebase\JWT\JWT::encode($payload , $secretKey);
        }catch (Exception $exception){
            $this->throwError(JWT_PROCESSING_ERROR , $exception->getMessage());
        }


    }
    public function deCodetoken(){
        try{
             $token = $this->getBearerToken();
             $payload = \Firebase\JWT\JWT::decode($token , SECURITY_KEY , ['HS256']);
             return $payload;

        }catch (Exception $exception){
            $this->throwError(ACCESS_TOKEN_ERROR , $exception->getMessage());
        }
    }



}
```

and the last class is **Rest.php** :

```
require_once ("Constans.php");
class Rest
{
    protected $HttpMethod;
    protected  $request;
    protected $data;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->HttpMethod = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
        if($this->checkValidhttpMethod()) {




            try{
                $handler = fopen('php://input', 'r');
                $this->request =  stream_get_contents($handler);
            }catch (Exception $exception){
                //TODO HANDLE EXEPTION
            }


             $this->validateRequest();

        }
    }

    public function checkValidhttpMethod(){
        if(empty($this->HttpMethod) or !in_array($this->HttpMethod,ACCEPTABLE_HTTP_METHOD)){
            $this->throwError(NOT_VALID_HTTP_METHOD,NOT_VALID_HTTP_METHOD_Message);
        }
        return true;
    }
    public function setJsonheader(){
        header("content-type: application/json");
    }

    public function validateRequest(){
        if($_SERVER['CONTENT_TYPE'] !== 'application/json'){
            $this->throwError(REQUEST_CONTENT_NOT_VALID , REQUEST_CONTENT_NOT_VALID_MESSAGE);

        }
        try{
            $this->data = json_decode($this->request , true);

        }catch (Exception $exception){
            //TODO HANDLE EXEPTION



        }


    }


    public function processAPI(){

    }

    public function throwError($code , $message){
        $this->setJsonheader();
        echo json_encode(['error' => ['status' => $code , 'message' => $message]]);
        exit;
    }

    public function returnResponse($code , $data){
        $this->setJsonheader();
        echo json_encode(['response' => ['status' => $code , 'result' => $data ]]);
        exit;
    }

    //TODO SQL injection Validate
    public function validateParameter($fieldName , $value , $dataType , $required = true){
        if($required  && empty($value)){
            $this->throwError(PARAMETR_REQUIRED,PARAMETR_REQUIRED_MESSAGE . $fieldName);
        }
        //TODO SQL injection



        //TODO CHECK The All Data Type
        switch ($dataType){
            case BOOLEAN :
                if(!is_bool($value)){
                    $this->throwError(PARAMETR_DATA_TYPE_NOT_VALID , PARAMETR_DATA_TYPE_NOT_VALID_MESSAGE . $fieldName);
                }
                break;
            case INTEGER :
                if(!is_numeric($value)){
                    $this->throwError(PARAMETR_DATA_TYPE_NOT_VALID , PARAMETR_DATA_TYPE_NOT_VALID_MESSAGE . $fieldName);
                }
                break;
            case STRING :
                if(!is_string($value)){
                    $this->throwError(PARAMETR_DATA_TYPE_NOT_VALID , PARAMETR_DATA_TYPE_NOT_VALID_MESSAGE . $fieldName);
                }
                break;
            case DONT_CARE :
                break;
            default:

                break;
        }


        return $value;


    }

    public function arrayFinddeep($array, $search)
    {

        foreach($array as $key => $value) {
            if (is_array($value)) {
                $sub = $this->arrayFinddeep($value, $search);
                if (count($sub)) {
                    return $sub;
                }
            } elseif ($key === $search) {
                return $value;
            }
        }

        return array();
    }

    /**
     * Get hearder Authorization
     * */
    function getAuthorizationHeader(){
        $headers = null;
        if (isset($_SERVER['Authorization'])) {
            $headers = trim($_SERVER["Authorization"]);
        }
        else if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'])) { //Nginx or fast CGI
            $headers = trim($_SERVER["HTTP_AUTHORIZATION"]);
        } elseif (function_exists('apache_request_headers')) {
            $requestHeaders = apache_request_headers();
            // Server-side fix for bug in old Android versions (a nice side-effect of this fix means we don't care about capitalization for Authorization)
            $requestHeaders = array_combine(array_map('ucwords', array_keys($requestHeaders)), array_values($requestHeaders));
            //print_r($requestHeaders);
            if (isset($requestHeaders['Authorization'])) {
                $headers = trim($requestHeaders['Authorization']);
            }
        }
        return $headers;
    }
    /**
     * get access token from header
     * */
    function getBearerToken() {
        $headers = $this->getAuthorizationHeader();
        // HEADER: Get the access token from the header
        if (!empty($headers)) {
            if (preg_match('/Bearer\s(\S+)/', $headers, $matches)) {
                return $matches[1];
            }
        }
        $this->throwError(AUTHORIZATION_HEADER_NOT_FOUND , AUTHORIZATION_HEADER_NOT_FOUND_MESSAGE);

    }


}
```

all queries go along **queryExecute** function in **api.php** class and recently I got that the **bindParam** function is not going to work fine too.

I really don't have any idea where the problem is, as In the reference said its somehow related to DB queries result. I try to use **mysqli** also but it did not work.

any help will be appreciated :-)

Comment: It can be everywhere You need to click raw button of postman result tab and get whole word. Then you can use the word for 'Find in Path' property of your IDE.

Comment: @HakanSONMEZ thanks for answering. I think its an error generate by PHP on the result of SQL bad result as Fedeco said in the link I referenced.

Comment: @Fedeco answer pretty same problem in silex framework